# How to change colour of "View Cart" and carty counter in woocommerce cart dropdown menu?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, drop-down-menu, cart

Im building a website in wordpress using the Sydney theme and woocommerce.

I would like to change the view cart at the bottom of the dropdown menu from white text to black, as well as the cart counter from white to black.

This is the URL for the website product category:https://www.justordinarilyodd.com/product-category/postcards/

Ive googled CSS script to change it but I cant find any that effect the text and NOT the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.woocommerce #content input.button, .woocommerce #respond input#submit, .woocommerce a.button, .woocommerce button.button, .woocommerce input.button, .woocommerce-page #content input.button, .woocommerce-page #respond input#submit, .woocommerce-page a.button, .woocommerce-page button.button, .woocommerce-page input.button {
    color:black !important;
}

.cart-amount {
    color:black !important;
}
```

Update: and for cart counter problem try this:

```
.site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart .woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons .button:not(.checkout) {
color: #00102e !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the cart counter problem but not the view cart issue

Comment: i edited my answer, try using additional code